# How to reference instances in a layered model - The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am developing  solution with 3 layers:

- UI (Winform)
- Storage (Class Library)
- Business layer (Class Library)

UI references Business, Business references Storage.

The business layer contains a class "controller" that will drive the interaction between layers.

The controller class is initiated from the main() in the UI.
Th controller on its turn initiates an instance from the business class

**However** the initiated object is not usable in the controller class.
What is the thinking that we are doing wrong?

```
/* UI: Program.cs */ 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Business;

namespace UI
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Business.Controller instController = new Business.Controller(); 

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new UI());
        }
    }
```

Business.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Storage;

namespace Business
{
    public class Business
    {

        private int myVar;

        public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

Controller.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Business
{
    public class Controller
    {
        Business instBusiness = new Business();

        /* line below fails, the instBusiness is not recognized) */

        instBusiness

    }
}
```

[image: Please find error here]

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? You can't access methods belonging to `instBusiness` outside of a method.

Comment: Understood, beginners fault clarified with explanation below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't execute arbitrary code inside a class without a method:

```
public class Controller
{

    // Fields, properties, methods and events go here...

    // note, this only works because its initializing a field 
    // its the same as initializing in a constructor
    Business instBusiness = new Business();
  
    // nope, not going to work
    // instBusiness

    public Controller()
    { 
       // yay!
       instBusiness.MyProperty = 5
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    { 
       // yayer!
       instBusiness.MyProperty = 5
    }
}
```

---

[Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

> A method is a code block that contains a series of statements. A
> program causes the statements to be executed by calling the method and
> specifying any required method arguments. In C#, every executed
> instruction is performed in the context of a method. The Main method
> is the entry point for every C# application and it is called by the
> common language runtime (CLR) when the program is started.